# Proverb to explain the given situation

Tags: proverbs

I am giving a competitive exam. During my exams my brother got ill, so all my family members went to the hospital in order to examine my brother. Home alone, I learn that they will not return for two days, then I got ill with a serious allergy so that I can't even write my exams.

Is there any proverb to explain above situation?

Editing to above context is valid.

Answer (score 3):

*[When it rains it pours](http://www.idiomeanings.com/idioms/when-it-rains-it-pours/)*:

> many difficult things always happen at the same time
>
> idiommeanings.com

Also delivered as, *[It never rains but it pours](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/It+never+rains+but+it+pours)*:

> Good (or bad) things do not just happen a few at a time, but in large
>   numbers all at once.
>
> idioms.thefreedictionary.com

Comment: Isn't there another particularly appropriate to this situation? Something like "Trouble comes in threes."

Answer (score 1):

**[It's (just) one thing after another!](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/It%27s+one+thing+after+another!)**

> - something that you say when bad things keep happening to you.
>
>   - We had our car stolen last week. It's one thing after another at the moment.

(TFD)

Answer (score 0):

Misfortunes never come singly.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/misfortunes_never_come_singly